# Copying authorization and groups in hybris

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud, user-permissions, role-base-authorization

Dears,

Kindly help me on below queries

1. How to copy standard permission group to custom permission group in back office?
2. while new user login, initial dialog box not appearing in backoffice?
3. How to download and upload user permission groups in backoffice ?

Thank You,
Venkatesh

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB function for copying authorizations. Maybe you can use export / import function in backoffice if your version is newer. Also you can use impex engine for export and import.

I didn't see any initial dialog box in backoffice. May be you try to asking perspective selection box. User need exact roles for multiple perspective selection box.